# Java KeyListener Treating Variables Like They're Static

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am trying to make a JLabel that acts as a button, where when you press it, the next key you press becomes the text. When I add one of the class to a JPanel, it works fine. However, if I add more, only the first one added works. This is the class:

```
package foo;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelButton extends JLabel implements MouseListener, KeyListener{
    String text = "";
    boolean editMode = false;
    public LabelButton(){
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    public LabelButton(String text){
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        this.text = text;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        if(!editMode){
            g.setColor(new Color(210,210,210));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(new Color(140,140,140));
            g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
            FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
            Rectangle textrect = new Rectangle(1,1,getWidth()+2,getHeight()-1);
            int textx = (textrect.width - metrics.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int texty = ((textrect.height - metrics.getHeight()) / 2) + metrics.getAscent();
            g.setColor(new Color(40,40,40));
            g.drawString(text, textx, texty);
        }else{
            g.setColor(new Color(160,160,160));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(new Color(210,210,210));
            g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
            FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
            Rectangle textrect = new Rectangle(1,1,getWidth()+2,getHeight()-1);
            int textx = (textrect.width - metrics.stringWidth("...")) / 2;
            int texty = ((textrect.height - metrics.getHeight()) / 2) + metrics.getAscent();
            g.setColor(new Color(40,40,40));
            g.drawString("...", textx, texty);
        }
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getButton() == 1){
            editMode = !editMode;
            System.out.println(text);
            repaint();
        }
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        editMode = false;
        repaint();
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(text);
        if(editMode){
            text = (String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar()).toUpperCase());
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar()).toUpperCase());
            editMode = false;
            repaint();
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

I have no clue whats wrong, and I need help. Thanks!

Comment: Side-note: there is a lot of duplication in your code, you should aim to reduce it to the bare minimum. Look at your constructors and paint method, you have much more code than actual logic.

Comment: What is your expected behavior and what is your observed behavior? Please give us a complete description of these.

Comment: Please see edits to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KeyListeners are **very** brittle when it comes to component focus -- they only work if the listened to component gets focus.

Your first component is grabbing the focus and is not letting it go, and there in lies your problem, since this means that the other focus "hungry" components won't work. One solution is to avoid KeyListeners, something I generally do, and usually in favor of Key Bindings.

Another is to grab focus in your mouselistener:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == 1) {
        editMode = !editMode;

        // **** added ****
        if (editMode) {
            requestFocusInWindow();
        }            
    }
}
```

Side note: I would prefer using `mousePressed` over `mouseClicked` as the former will capture more mouse presses than the latter.

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestLabelButton extends JPanel {

    public TestLabelButton() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 10, 10));

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            add(new LabelButton("Text " + (i + 1)));
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TestLabelButton mainPanel = new TestLabelButton();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestLabelButton");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class LabelButton extends JLabel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 160;
    private static final int PREF_H = 40;
    private static final Color NON_EDIT_BG = new Color(210, 210, 210);
    private static final Color EDIT_BG = new Color(160, 160, 160);
    private static final Color EDIT_RECT_COLOR = new Color(210, 210, 210);
    private static final Color NON_EDIT_RECT_COLOR = new Color(140, 140, 140);
    private static final Color TEXT_COLOR = new Color(40, 40, 40);
    public static final String EDITING_TEXT = "...";
    private boolean editMode = false;

    public LabelButton() {
        this("");
    }

    public LabelButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        addMouseListener(new MyMouse());
        addKeyListener(new MyKey());
        setFocusable(true);
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(NON_EDIT_BG);
        setForeground(TEXT_COLOR);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(NON_EDIT_RECT_COLOR));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return superSz;
        }
        int prefW = Math.max(superSz.width, PREF_W);
        int prefH = Math.max(superSz.height, PREF_H);
        return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
    }

    public void setEditMode(boolean editMode) {
        this.editMode = editMode;
        Color bg = editMode ? EDIT_BG : NON_EDIT_BG;
        Color rectColor = editMode ? EDIT_RECT_COLOR : NON_EDIT_RECT_COLOR;
        String drawText = editMode ? "..." : getText();

        setBackground(bg);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(rectColor));
        setText(drawText);

        if (editMode) {
            requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }

    public boolean isEditMode() {
        return editMode;
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == 1) {
                setEditMode(!isEditMode());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            setEditMode(false);
        }
    }

    private class MyKey extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (editMode) {
                String text = (String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar()).toUpperCase());
                setText(text);
                setEditMode(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: no need to override paintComponent if you're just drawing text!

Comment: This was amazing, thank you! Also I use mousePressed most of the time, however for this I wanted the full mouse press and release. Thanks for the advise though.